# How do I define either of 2 classes with TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have:

```
class CreateYouTubeConversationDto {
    @ApiProperty({ required: true })
    youtubeId: string;
}

class CreateDirectConversationDto {
    @ApiProperty({ required: true })
    imageUrl: string;

    @ApiProperty({ required: true })
    createdByUserId: string;
}
```

I want to create a new class that is either of those. If it was a `type`, I'd do:
`type Convo = CreateYouTubeConversationDto  | CreateDirectConversationDto`

But since it's a class, I cannot. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What's the advantage of having the new object as a class rather than a union type? How do you want to use it, such that a `class` is advantageous?

Comment: I'm using the decorators, so I think that's why I need a `class`

Comment: It may be helpful to add which framework you're using, since you're trying to satisfy the decorators. I don't think there's a general solution for this problem for all classes in Typescript, but there's a specific solution to the problem in specs like [Nest GraphQL](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/unions) or [Nest OpenAPI/Swagger](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger#oneof-anyof-allof) (`anyOf`).

Comment: Using nestjs with OpenAPI

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what does it say? Because a union of classes does [seem to work fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa0CeB7ArgFxwCMBTASQBMAuaCPAJwEsA7AcwG5V1gsna6dgeLHQAUASkSd00PAAsGEAHTZ8RMuWgBeaAHIwhYDqkBfVKZSpQkGACFJaaAwC2YFsQCqdENT7N2U7l56ASFRCWQHdDkFRWdXDy8tXXJiADMjB3NzVDwMAAdiaBssOST4AB8i1EseWmgwamLS7SZiAHc4cRqg6EJGktkk1o6bcSA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you might want to create a type, so for that you'd do:

```
type Convo =
  | typeof CreateYouTubeConversationDto
  | typeof CreateDirectConversationDto;
```

But if you truly want a new class? And I'm assuming you don't want inheritance? You could do this:

```
class Foo implements Convo {
  // look for errors that you didn't properly
  // implement Convo here
}
```

Comment: Getting: `A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.`